# How do I find the Firebase account I made with an IOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase

This is going to sound really stupid, but I'm trying to figure out what email another developer used to make our Firebase account for an IOS account. Is it possible to figure that out from the xCode and the IOS app?

Comment: Do you mean what google account he used to create your firebase database?

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine this from just the app. That would actually be pretty bad, because that means all users of the app could find the same details. But you can look up the people with access to the app from the Firebase console.

In the settings menu in the top left (with the ⚙️icon), there is a <kbd>Users and permissions</kbd> option. Clicking that brings you to a list of the users that have access to this project, or click this handy [direct link](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/iam) and select the project. The creator is typically the user marked as <kbd>Owner</kbd>.